Is it possible to convexify the inequality constraint $z \leq x^3 \cdot y$?
Is there a way to convexify the inequality constraint $z \leq x^3 \cdot y$ in a nonlinear optimization problem with $x, y, z$ being nonnegative variables?

It depends what you mean by convexify in relation to the rest of your model. For example if you are willing to replace your decision variable $z$ by $t=1/z$ then you have $tx^3y\geq 1$, which is convex. Of course now you would have to be able to pull $t$ through the rest of your model in a convex fashion. It cannot be convexified as-is, without some change of variables.
